# Method called recursive onResume Activity java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I am getting this exception in datetimeformat and it runs multiple ti

```
public String parseDateToddMMyyyy(String time) {
    String inputPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    String outputPattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputPattern);
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern);

    Date date = null;
    String str = null;

    try {
        date = inputFormat.parse(time);
        str = outputFormat.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str;
}
```

i am getting below exception

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
   at com.pixako.trackn.BaseActivity.parseDateToddMMyyyy(Unknown Source)
   at com.pixako.trackn.BaseActivity.parseDateToddMMyyyy(Unknown Source)
   at com.pixako.trackn.BaseActivity.parseDateToddMMyyyy(Unknown Source)
   at com.pixako.trackn.BaseActivity.parseDateToddMMyyyy(Unknown Source)
   at com.pixako.trackn.BaseActivity.parseDateToddMMyyyy(Unknown Source)
   at com.pixako.trackn.BaseActivity.parseDateToddMMyyyy(Unknown Source)
   at com.pixako.trackn.BaseActivity.parseDateToddMMyyyy(Unknown Source)
   at com.pixako.trackn.BaseActivity.parseDateToddMMyyyy(Unknown Source)
   at com.pixako.trackn.BaseActivity.parseDateToddMMyyyy(Unknown Source)
   at com.pixako.trackn.BaseActivity.parseDateToddMMyyyy(Unknown Source)
   at com.pixako.trackn.JobListTest.onResume(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1277)
   at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7142)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3850)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3914)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3070)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1659)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
```

Here i am calling it

```
public void orderingResult(JSONArray Result) {    
for (int i = 0; i < Result.length(); i++) {
try {
     JSONObject jobj = Result.getJSONObject(i);
     try{               jobj.put("ausTimeJobDate",parseDateToddMMyyyy(jobj.getString("Job_Date")));
     }catch(Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace(); 
     }
  }catch(Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
  }
```

}

I am not able to understand why this function is calling multiple time

Note: this function is not recursive

Comment: can you add where are you calling this function

Comment: i have added it @androidAhmed

Comment: Can you paste the entire method for `com.pixako.trackn.JobListTest.onResume`? Based on your stack trace, that's the last entry point before you get into the recursive loop so there may be something there (although I do agree that this is very strange)

Comment: How big is the payload on that Result Json

Comment: @Dracarys for the above crash in Result i have 5 entries each entries is JSONObject and each JSONObject have 100 parameters then you can say that you have 3Kb data in Result

Comment: @kha in onResume there is no recurring methods call and the hirarchy of the function call is also totally different onResume->jobListResponse->orderingResult but in exception jobListResponse is totally ignored

Comment: @kha previously i am calling it in ExpandableListViewAdapter same issue is happening so i have update my code and add it into orderingResult still same exception

Comment: Then unfortunately I have no advise to give other than try and put in a break point in the method and see where/how/when/why it's calling itself recursively. It's not obvious form the code provided.

Comment: @kha it is not happening each and every time it happens randomly and it happens on release build is there any way to avoid this exception?

Comment: as I seen you call function of parse date parseDateToddMMyyyy(String) inside loop which call many times depend in number of Result.length()
you can make SimpleDateFormat  to null
or can make it global
so you can nake garbage collector remove the object, or create one  instead of create  many times  depend on number of Result which is (500) as you told

Answer (score 0):

How many times do you call this function? Create a SimpleDateFormat objects once, not every time you call.

Comment: it depend upon the response but most of the time it called in between 5 to 10 time this function is running perfectly fine a month ago but with new build it happens randomly once in a day sometime it never happens